# Change image on annotation with timer - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I get array from server, and must to show annotation with coordination (array with coord) on map
and I have array "status". Value of array must change annotation image (1 = green picture, 2 - red pic, 3 - yellow pic)
So it's work
But, when I update my location array and status array, my picture are change.
The image must change, when I get another status, but all time, there are change.
How to solve this problem?

```
class SuperPin: MKPointAnnotation {
var lon: Double!
var lat: Double!
var name: String!
var status: String!
}


func DriverData(string: String) {
    if (string != nil)
  //there I'm get my array
    var t = 0
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
        let ann = self.myMap.annotations.filter { $0 !== self.myMap.userLocation }
        self.myMap.removeAnnotations(ann)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            do {
                var pin: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.longitude[t].doubleValue, longitude: self.latitude[t].doubleValue)

                var my_color = SuperPin()

            if (self.status[t].toInt() == 1){
                my_color.status = "1.png"
            } else {
            if (self.status[t].toInt() == 2){
                my_color.status = "2.png"
            } else {
                my_color.status = "3.png"
                }
                }
                my_color.lat = self.latitude[t].doubleValue
                my_color.lon = self.longitude[t].doubleValue
                my_color.coordinate.latitude = my_color.lon
                my_color.coordinate.longitude = my_color.lat
                my_color.title = self.name[t]
                self.myMap.addAnnotation(my_color)
                t++
            } while (t < namearr.count)
        })
    })
    } else {
        timer1.invalidate()
    }
}





 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    let reuseID = "test"
    var anView = myMap.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseID) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        anView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseID)
        anView!.image = UIImage(named: "usrloc")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
        anView!.canShowCallout = true
    }

    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseID)
        let cpa = annotation as! SuperPin
        anView!.image = UIImage(named: cpa.status)
        anView!.canShowCallout = true
    } else {
        anView!.annotation = annotation
    }

        return anView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

--> First Remove all annotation from your mapview which are came from old array then you are getting or updating your location and getting new annotations on map so try the below logic. It help me fine and may help you also.

```
var arrannotations = NSMutableArray();
map.removeAnnotations(map.annotations);
for var i = 0; i <arrannotations; i++
{
map.addAnnotation(arrannotations.objectAtIndex[i])
}
```

Comment: let ann = self.myMap.annotations.filter { $0 !== self.myMap.userLocation }
        self.myMap.removeAnnotations(ann)
There I delete my annotation

Comment: and now add new annotation again with new images that will definately solve your problem.

Comment: so now I don't understand you)
may you help in Skype mb?)

Comment: skype not allowed for at this time i can do it later on after 2 hours. if you can.

Comment: Mb you don't understand my question, I send you a full code.
Si, I'm wating for you